# Puppet Oracle home setting

Tags: oracle, puppet, cx-oracle

here is my code for installing cx_Oracle.

```
  exec { 'build_cxoracle':
    command     => 'python2.7 setup.py build',
    path        => '/bin:/usr/bin',
    environment => 'ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64',
    cwd         => '/tmp/cx_Oracle-5.1.2',
    require     => Exec[untar_oracle],
  }
```

this fails with error below,

```
Exec[build_cxoracle]/returns: Traceback (most recent call last):
Exec[build_cxoracle]/returns:   File "setup.py", line 180, in <module>
Exec[build_cxoracle]/returns:     raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate Oracle include files")
Exec[build_cxoracle]/returns: distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate Oracle include files
```

after reading blogs from other people I came to conclusion that this is ORACLE_HOME error, but I thought **environment => 'ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64',** will takecare of it. apparently that's not the case.

Can someone tell me how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you add that path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` too? And did you install the SDK package as well as the basic or basic-lite?

Comment: Yes, here is what I am doing for that.

Comment: Yes, here is what I am doing for that.`file { '/etc/profile.d/oracle.sh':
    ensure  => present,
    content => template('db/oracle.sh.erb'),
  } 
`
    `file {'/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf':
    ensure  => present,
    mode    => 0640,
    content => '/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib',
  }` and running ldconfig after that. And oracle.sh.erb has export `ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is what I am doing for that.

```
file { '/etc/profile.d/oracle.sh': 
         ensure => present, 
         content => template('db/oracle.sh.erb'), 
} 

file {'/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf': 
         ensure => present, mode => 0640, 
        content => '/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib', 
}
```

and running ldconfig after that. And oracle.sh.erb has export

```
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
```

in it